# Change wordpress post author on the fly while publishing the post

Tags: wordpress, publish, author

I am developing my site and require to change post author id on the fly while publishing.

All post will be write and publish by admin but as content provided by different author and need to change post author id from admin to other author ( author id will get from custom field )

So how to do this on the fly while publishing.

Does the author info *have* to come from the custom field? Because you could do  this straight in the UI manually.

- Enable the "author" block in the display options when creating a post
- Change the author in the drop-down menu

Here is my theme metabox.php code I am using wpalchemy metabox script and below code is in my cpt loop php file

```
// getting custom field value from image_artist
// this is giving value like artist_login_name / id
$png_gallery_meta->the_field('image_artist');
$artist_info = $png_gallery_meta->get_the_value();

// to separate artist_login_name and id
$string = $artist_info;
$artist = substr($string, 0, stripos($string, "/") );

// getting first name and last name from user id
$author_first_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->first_name;

$author_last_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->last_name;
```

So I am using above code to get user info from custom field dropdown selection box. Now how can I use above value to change id on the fly while admin publish the post the post author id should change with above id value get from selection box. I hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post_id = $post->ID; // change this to whathever
$user_id = '4'; // change this too

$the_post = array();
$the_post['ID'] = $post_id;
$the_post['post_author'] = $user_id;

wp_insert_post( $the_post );
```

The code above will update the currently looped through post (via $post->ID) with an author with ID of 4.

Read how wp_insert_post works [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). Basically, if you pass it an ID of a post that already exists it will update that post with the new information you pass to it. (the author ID in this case)

If you want to grab things from the custom fields you can use:

```
$author = get_post_meta($this->ID, 'author_id', TRUE);
```

More info on [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code but still little confused. How to use exactly with my code and in which file I should place wp_insert_post code to make it works. Please refer my code with updated question so if you can help me in specific way. I would really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Does the author info *have* to come from the custom field? Because you could do  this straight in the UI manually.

- Enable the "author" block in the display options when creating a post
- Change the author in the drop-down menu

Here is my theme metabox.php code I am using wpalchemy metabox script and below code is in my cpt loop php file

```
// getting custom field value from image_artist
// this is giving value like artist_login_name / id
$png_gallery_meta->the_field('image_artist');
$artist_info = $png_gallery_meta->get_the_value();

// to separate artist_login_name and id
$string = $artist_info;
$artist = substr($string, 0, stripos($string, "/") );

// getting first name and last name from user id
$author_first_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->first_name;

$author_last_name = get_userdata(basename($string))->last_name;
```

So I am using above code to get user info from custom field dropdown selection box. Now how can I use above value to change id on the fly while admin publish the post the post author id should change with above id value get from selection box. I hope now it is more clear.